# laravel backpack - crud select change filter

Tags: laravel-backpack

I am using [backpack CRUD](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-example) in laravel 5.3

I have 3 models: product, country and region. And I am looking way to similar function as jquery onchange ajax call.
Product crud has select for county and region. If I selected country, region select should filtered by selected country.

I don't know find crud function for this or way to insert js to edit view for one controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no pre-built field that will help you. Possible solutions:

1. [create a custom field type](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-fields#section-custom-field-types) for this purpose, starting from `select2` or `select2_from_ajax`, that watches the change event on the first field and filters the second;
2. include the same javascript in your `public\vendor\backpack\crud\js\form.js`;

I would recommend option (1), seems cleaner to me.

Hope it helps, cheers!